# Given $m$ operations of coloring. What is color of $i$-th ball ?

Tags: algorithms, intervals

There are given $n$ balls. Their indexes: $\{1,...,n\}$.
Initially all of them are painted in $green$. (other possible color in my problem is $red$).
It is possible to paint interval of balls in color $red$ or $green$, for example $paint([a,b], green)$ - ball in given interval will be paint in green.

What's more, there are given $m\ge n$ operations of painting. After executing all $m$ painting our task is answer to question: What is color of ball $i$, where $i\in \{1,...,n\}$.

I can solve it by simple simulation coloring - I use BST interval tree. Hence, I get $O(m\lg n)$.

I am think about faster solution. It is my problem, indeed. It is easy to see that good idea is process operations in reverse order (from $m$ to $1$).  Have you any idea ?

Comment: [Related question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14228/how-to-query-and-update-ranges-of-arrays).

Comment: When I use your link I get $O(m \sqrt{n} \log(n))$. It is worse than $O(m\lg n)$

Comment: $\mathcal{O}(m \log n)$ seems pretty good already, I assume you could prove this as a lower bound in a comparison model. I guess if you're after practical performance, you should consider the option of using a static tree (sometimes called segment tree) instead of a BST. Theoretically, it might be possible to achieve something like $\mathcal{O}(m \log \log n)$  using [y-fast tries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-fast_trie) or [vEB trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Emde_Boas_tree), but I can't imagine these being useful in practice

Comment: I'm confused.  What is the input?  Are the inputs $n,m,i$?  So you only need to answer the question for a single $i$?  If so, it seems that this problem can be solved in $O(m)$ time: each time you receive an operation, you simply check whether $i$ is in the interval or not and update its color as needed.  If that's not what you intended, please update the question to clarify.